# Migration mechanism of Spring Boot for AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds, liquibase

I'm looking for way to setup migration mechanism like liquibase or mybatis for AWS RDS.

I have Spring Boot application. And probably i can use liquibase for example for postgresql in AWS RDS. In this case I think I have two ways: 1) add liquibase to my project and run migration in Cincinnati/CD.2) or create separate project with liqoibase only.

But I want to find another way to implement migrations mechanism.

What else can I use for migrations in AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS RDS is just providing your PostgreSQL database server. What you do with the tables and data inside that server is not any different than what you would do with the tables and data inside any other PostgreSQL server. There are no extra or different schema migration options available to you in AWS RDS.

Your options for schema migration tools in Spring Boot are really Liquibase or Flyway.